# Cordova CLI - After update, any and all commands fail with "Error: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined"

Tags: macos, cordova, command-line-interface

I updated cordova using `sudo npm update -g cordova`

After update, I have been unable to use any CLI command to prepare, build or run any of my projects.

I get the following error

> Error: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined

I tried searching StackOverflow for help, but solutions available did not work for me.

I have tried updating again, and installing a specific version again but to no effect.
The only step left is to uninstall cordova and npm and re-install but if anyone has a better solution, please do help.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Oh man, i keep running into this error. It seems that my project has errors.

Comment: Finally fixed, created new cordova project, added the plugins and platforms and coped over the www folder contents, and that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anybody who runs into the above error message after update of either nodejs, npm or (especially) cordova.

The solution was to create a fresh cordova project using `cordova create <projectname>` and then install the plugins and platforms that you are building for.

The next step is to copy over the config.xml preferences (only preferences, exact copy of config did not work in my case) and www folder contents.

I even tried uninstall nodejs, npm, cordova and re-installing them individually and in random order only to make things worse.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the config.xml syntax for whitelist. Instead of `uri` you should use `origin`:

```
<access uri="*" />
```

should be:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: I also made a typo a few days ago and missed it had  <allow-navigation origin="*.example.com"/> instead of  <allow-navigation href="*.example.com"/>

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my particular problem was the way that cordova identifies the project root folder. The logic is... convoluted. In my case, there were some trash folders in my `Documents` folder, including a `www` folder from a very old cordova project. I wiped out the `platforms` folder in my current project, which caused cordova to go up one directory and use the trash config.xml from the `www` folder in my document folder.

Bottom line: run `cordova info` to see what `config.xml` data is being loaded, you might be surprised.

Comment: Interesting, I still have that **troublesome** cordova app dump with me, will try and report back with findings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-name`. If any complainsts about a `cordova_plugins.js` file is shown, do a `cordova platform remove ios|android` (whichever platform is shown). If this doesn't work, go into your `plugins` folder and remove the plugin folder as well as its entry in the `fetch.json`.
2. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-name`.
3. Add back your platform using `cordova platform add ios|android`.

You're good to go. No need to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

ok because of this line I added without no intent when trying to fix proxy error that causing problem:

```
 <access origin="*" />
```

where? missing atribute `href` make it cannot parse. then cause error

```
(node:3362) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
    at Url.parse (url.js:103:11)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:97:13)
    at parseWhitelistUrlForATS (/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/prepare.js:1005:20)
    at /platforms/ios/cordova/lib/prepare.js:965:23
```

delete this line make it work